# How to set same height value by using jquery if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the window is re-size, if the height of `#cat` is less than the height of `#dog`, the height of `#cat` should be set equal to height of `#dog`.

```
    $(window).resize(function() {

    if ( ('#cat').height < ('#dog').height )

    $( ('#cat').height = ('#dog').height )

    else nothing
```

What should be the Jquery code?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `$('#cat').height()`

Comment: HI arun can you please post the full jquery codes

Comment: what you want actually..question is unclear

Comment: a quick peruse of the jQuery docs would set you on the right track, its unclear what you've actually tried at this stage...?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
 var cHeight = $("#cat").height();
 var dHeight = $("#dog").height();
 if(cGHeight < dHeight){
  $("#dHeight").height(cHeight);
 }
```

Comment: To set the height using .height(), you wanna pass the new height as the argument

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.max` to solve this without the need for an if statement. Also note that it's a good idea to debounce the `resize` event so that it doesn't make the UI appear jumpy when then window is being resized. Try this:

```
var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        var $cat = $('#cat'), $dog = $('#dog');
        $cat.height(Math.max($cat.height(), $dog.height()));
    }, 100);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/xwaoe42e/)

Comment: I'm curious, can you elaborate on what you mean by debouncing?

Comment: It means that the logic attached to the event wont be executed until the event has finished and has not been raised again within a set timeout. Ths is needed for `scroll` and `resize` events mostly as the event is raised for every single pixel that the UI is updated by. Therefore is you resize the window from 100px high to 200px, you would possibly be calling the logic 100 times. My code above reduces that to just one call.

Comment: Rory may be there have some Brackets"() or {}" problem can you please fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ( $('#cat').height() < $('#dog').height() ) {
        var dogHeight = $('#dog').height()
        $('#cat').height(dogHeight)
    }
})
```

If nothing is expected to happen in the `else` block, you don't need it.